# Write to console Unicode (UTF-16) text with Windows WinAPI functions?

Tags: assembly, unicode, console, x86-64, masm

I have a 64 bit masm code that outputs to a console. The problem is that by using `WriteConsoleW`, i'm not able to redirect the output of a command or anything since it only writes to the console buffer. But using `WriteFile` adds spaces between each character since the 16 bit chars have the high-order bits zeroed out. How can i print Unicode text with `WriteFile` ?

I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks) that I could use BOM but that just doesn't work for me (I added another `WriteFile` call that writes the two bytes `FF FE` before the second `WriteFile` call, but it just printed a white rectangle and nothing else).

Here's the code:

```
extern GetStdHandle: proc
extern WriteConsoleW: proc
.data?
    written dq ?
.data
    string dw 0048h,0065h,006ch,006ch,006fh,0020h,0057h,006fh,0072h,006ch,0064h,0021h
    len equ $-string
.code
main proc
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 020h
    and rsp, -10h

    mov rcx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, offset string
    mov r8, len
    mov r9, written
    call    WriteConsoleW

    add rsp, 020h
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
main endp
end
```

When i swap `WriteConsoleW` to `WriteFile`, it prints correctly when ran through visual studio, but when i run the generated `exe` from a command line, instead of printing `Hello World!` it prints `H e l l o  W o r l d !`

Does anyone know how to deal with that ?

EDIT:
I'm not sure how to understand this but somehow when i use `WriteFile` instead, the 16 bit characters get printed wrong only when i execute the program alone. However when i redirect the output to the `echo` command it prints normally:
[image: Powershell printing output]

Comment: If WriteFile to the console prints with spaces, probably the terminal you're running on isn't expecting UTF-16.  Or else there's some extra level of translation and complexity I don't know about.  BTW, you don't need to obscure your string by manually translating it to numbers; `dw 'H', 'e', 'l', ...` will assemble to the same words in memory.  I'm confident that any Windows Unicode shenanigans happen only during run-time, not for something as simple as MASM assembling your code.

Comment: Does `dw` mean double-word i.e. 32 bits?  That could be your problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, `dd` is "data doubleword".  `dw` is "data word" or "define word", a 16-bit integer since x86 type-width names originated with 8086.  It produces the same bytes in `.rdata` as `db 'H',0, 'e',0, ...` since x86 is little-endian.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for clarifying that for me.  I'm a lot more familiar with C and C++ than assembly these days I'm afraid.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah my bad for that x'] didn't mean to obfuscate them, i just wanted to make sure that they're 16 bits during my test (I also saw during debugging that the high order and low bytes are swapped in memory due to low-endianness  i guess). I will try to see if the issue was just the terminal then, because when i run on VS it's completely fine and interprets it as unicode correctly. It's just command prompt or powershell that are behaving weirdly which is shocking cause i at least thought powershell would support unicode =/ that's why i think i did something wrong

Comment: If you don't trust or understand your assembler, the way to be sure what bytes you're getting would be to use `db` with `0` bytes inserted manually, with the ASCII byte first for little-endian UTF-16.  But you've already verified with a debugger's hexdump that you're getting the least-significant byte of each 16-bit integer at the low address, as expected for little-endian.  That's not a "swap" per-se; it was never in 16-bit big-endian format in the first place, only text in your source code.  (And in text arabic numerals we always write the MSD on the left.  And leading zeros mean nothing.)

Comment: But anyway, I think Windows console windows are separate from the programs that run in them, like it's not `cmd.exe` that's drawing that GUI, it's Windows itself, because you ran a console application.  (In other OSes, the separation is even more clear: `xterm` is a separate program that runs fully in user-space, not part of the OS itself.  But since you are on Windows, you'll need a Windows answer, which I don't know.)

Comment: Per edit, `echo` may be not printing a space for null bytes.  Print something non_ASCII that is visible, like a Euro sign, that is outside the Latin-1 codepoint range.

Comment: I replaced `H` with the unicode for the euro sign (e.g. 20AC) and it prints like this: https://pasteboard.co/O5ues32rUUyK.png
Either way it seems echo is doing something weird so i'll just ignore that.. For now, I'll try to adapt your solution using the C runtime library, not sure how to link it to masm yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same APIs in C++ produce the same console output.  `WriteConsoleW` performs a character translation to the console that `WriteFile` doesn't.
`WriteFile` just sends bytes to the console which interprets them in the  current code page, which for me is 437 (OEM United States).

I was able to get it to work in C++ by calling `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` (set console code page to UTF-8) and then writing a UTF-8 string.  Note this [list of code page identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) which includes UTF-16 but it is only available for managed applications (e.g. C#).

I printed some non-ASCII to see if it came out correctly.

```cpp
// compiled with MSVS "cl /W4 /utf-8 test.cpp"
// source saved in UTF-8 as well.
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = u8"Hello, 马克"; // Note: need a chinese font, but cut/paste
                               // to Notepad and you'll see them if you don't.
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    auto h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD written;
    WriteFile(h, s, sizeof(s), &written, nullptr);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 马克
```

You should be able to adapt this to MASM easily.

If you are willing to use the C runtime library, then these APIs both work for UTF-16 if you set the console and file mode appropriately:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t s[] = L"Hello, 马克!";
    _write(_fileno(stdout), s, sizeof(s));
    int fd = _open("test.txt", _O_CREAT | _O_WRONLY | _O_U16TEXT);
    _write(fd, s, sizeof(s));
    _close(fd);
}
```

Output to console:

```
Hello, 马克!
```

Output to test.txt encoded in UTF-16LE.  Note that 马克 is the two unicode code points U+9A5C and U+514B:
[image: hexadecimal dump of test.txt]

**EDIT**

Here's a demo of `GetFileType`.  If run it writes to the console correctly.  If redirected to a file, e.g. "test > out.txt", the output file contains UTF-16LE-encoded data.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    auto h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    auto type = GetFileType(h);
    
    WCHAR s[] = L"Only 20\u20AC!";  // U+20AC is EURO sign.
    DWORD written;
    
    if(type == FILE_TYPE_DISK)
        WriteFile(h, s, sizeof(s) - sizeof(WCHAR) /* don't send the null */, &written, nullptr);
    else
        WriteConsoleW(h, s, sizeof(s) / sizeof(WCHAR) - 1, &written, nullptr);
}
```

Output to console:

```
Only 20€!
```

Output redirected to `out.txt`:
[image: hexadecimal dump of out.txt]

Comment: I've adapted it to masm, but somehow it still prints character by character =/ taking each 16 bit unicode as two different 8 bit chars. For my specific use-case I actually need a way to write UTF-16 characters without `WriteConsoleW`, your solution works correctly with UTF-8 chars though

Comment: @Lorenzo Even the Windows `fwprintf` calls `WriteConsoleW` under the covers when `stdout` is the console.  I set a breakpoint to check.  I think you'll have to detect and use the right API by using [`GetFileType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype).  Without the console supporting a UTF-16 codepage I think you're out of luck.

Comment: I tried GetFileType on the handle i'm getting and it returned `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` which is basically a console but I'm not sure i understand what i should do to adapt? I wouldn't mind using `WriteConsoleW` at all if only i could manipulate the output using redirections

Comment: @Lorenzo A file should come back as `FILE_TYPE_DISK`.  I'm also about ot edit my answer with a C runtime version if you are willing to call those instead of Win32 APIs.  I'm using the low-level C runtime but modifying the stdout mode and the file mode to support UTF-16.

Comment: @Lorenzo: This answer is saying that the normal way for a Windows console to support Unicode is via UTF-8, not UTF-16.  Library functions that can correctly output UTF-16 strings to the console must be doing it by converting to UTF-8 in a temporary buffer.  If you just wanted Unicode and don't care about UTF-16 specifically, use UTF-8 in the first place.  If you're lucky, that will even work with `db "Hello, 马克!"` strings in your MASM source, unlike UTF-16.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's not quite what is going on.  `WriteConsoleW` bypasses code page translation since Windows is UTF-16 internally.  `WriteFile` (like `WriteConsoleA`, btw) just "sends bytes" which the console interprets in the current code page and translates to the corresponding Unicode.  UTF-8 at least can handle all of Unicode.  In fact, if I run my test code and redirect to a file, the file contains the bytes sent, which are the UTF-16LE-encoded text, its just the console that is converting those bytes into the current code page (437 on my system).

Comment: @Lorenzo I tested `GetFileType` and it works.  See edit.